# Convert from binary to hex string

Tags: c

I have `char *` filled of bytes for example `0x01 0x02 0xff`. I need to make these bytes and print in human readable hex format like `"0102ff"`. What is the best way of doing that?

Comment: [Use standard C library functions.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Please show us you've done some research, at least.

Comment: Asking for "the best way" -- that means "answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
 char *p = "12345";
     // or with non string data. -> char p[5] = { 0x00, 0x56, 0x2C, 0x7a, 0x88 };
 int i;

 for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     printf("%02x ", p[i]);

 printf("\n");

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
for (i=0; i<sizeof(my_array);i++)
    printf("%hhx", (unsigned char) my_array[i])
```

where 'hh' means unsigned char, and 'x' means hexadecimal, in '%hhx' expression.

source:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/